# How to capture some event requests count out of all requests using Jmeter/any other tool

Tags: selenium, jmeter

We have scenario to be tested and capture requests and list down some of the requests count:

1. Browse the web application in any browser> F12/developer tools> there are some events captured (user events) out of other normal requests (we need to take the count of these user events).
2. Now trying to simulate the above scenario using Jmeter and get the events (user events) triggered after rendering the page.
3. Used Jmeter with Selenium Webdriver sampler> Able to launch the browser for the given url
4. View results tree> can see only one request i.e, sampler (jp@gc - webdriver sampler) with response code 200 and response body
5. Unable to get the requests as can see under F12 when manually browsed.
6. If I try blazemeter or http script recorder, it captures the user events but this event will be random for every refresh/accessing the url. Some times 4 times, some times 6 times or so..

How can this be captured (access the url, capture all the requests of that action) or any other way using Selenium or any other open source tools?

Comment: is your goal to capture only requests, being started by desired user actions?

Comment: Capture requests and see how many user events are triggered (analytics purpose) out of total requests. Please guide.

Comment: You have working webapp/website and for analytics purposes want to count any user actions (which of them are popular or not, etc.),yes?

Comment: Yes, it is web application. When home page or Login page is accessed, couple of event requests are getting triggered which needs to be captured and count. Please suggest.

Comment: If you want to gather such business statistics about your users activity, this is more front-end task, than for testing (with jmeter): you need set logging functions (maybe to DB) to desired gui elements (buttons, fields, etc.) -- it may be standalone js-script, thats running on your apps start.

Comment: Or do you need tech statistics about count of web requests? May be for finding "heavy" requests and bottle-necks of UI. If so, then you must not only count requests, but log anywhere time of their response. And with these numbers you'll have ability to recognize UI perfomance problems

Comment: Thanks for the update. However we though if it can be done through Jmeter, then can simulate concurrent users later part and see how many these specific user events out of all requests are triggered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180952/discussion-between-dan-brandt-and-laksh).